# How to find the class that throws an exception in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, exception

I am stuck with an exception that occurs in my `Java Spring MVC` application. The following gets displayed in the console:

```
22:17:55.614 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 update public.wc_content_definition set web_content_desc= was aborted. Call getNextException() to see the cause.
22:17:55.614 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(3)

22:17:55.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1175) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1251) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at com.smartwcm.core.userprofile.dao.impl.UserProfileDaoImpl.getUserProfile(UserProfileDaoImpl.java:40) [UserProfileDaoImpl.class:na]
    at com.smartwcm.core.wc.service.impl.WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.setViewUrlForProfile(WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.java:1098) [WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.smartwcm.core.wc.service.impl.WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.setWebcontentUrls(WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.java:1086) [WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.smartwcm.core.wc.service.impl.WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.saveOrUpdateWebContentDefinition(WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.java:222) [WebContentDefinitionServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.saveOrUpdateWebContentDefinition(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.smartwcm.core.usercollection.service.impl.UserCollectionServiceImpl.saveDefaultUserProfiles(UserCollectionServiceImpl.java:239) [UserCollectionServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.smartwcm.core.usercollection.service.impl.UserCollectionServiceImpl.addUsersToUserCollection(UserCollectionServiceImpl.java:147) [UserCollectionServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.addUsersToUserCollection(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.smartwcm.admin.usercollection.controller.UserCollectionController.addUsersToCollection(UserCollectionController.java:481) [UserCollectionController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: org.postgresql.jdbc2.PBatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 update public.wc_content_definition set web_content_desc= was aborted. Call getNextException() to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:107) ~[postgresql-7.4.1-jdbc3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    ... 110 common frames omitted
```

I am unable to find the exact method that throws the exception.  Is there any way to find the method or class from where this message originates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record you can define Exception breakpoints in Eclipse. You just need to click on "Add Java Exception Breakpoint". See image bellow. Please note there is a high performance impact on using Exception breakpoint (or using conditional breakpoints).

[image]

Comment: I found the exact issue with your help and thereby solved the issue. I never knew about this option and it was a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Generally** the exact reason for the Exception is at the **first line** of your Stack Trace, and for more information about the cause of that exception, you need to **gradually move down**, and the root cause can often be found somewhere near the bottom of the stack trace.

But in **most** cases, you can even get the cause of the exception from the **first few lines**..

I read your stack trace from top to bottom,

and this is the line which is actually throwing exception...

```
 at com.smartwcm.core.userprofile.dao.impl.UserProfileDaoImpl.getUserProfile(UserProfileDaoImpl.java:40) [UserProfileDaoImpl.class:na]
```

because all the lines above are related to hibernate, but this line is **specific to your application.**

Answer (score 1):

When you read the stack trace, look for the *first occurence* of your code package.

By looking at the trace you provided: the `org.hibernate.exception`, `org.hibernate.jdbc` and `org.hibernate.impl` looks an standard API packages.

So most probably, after those lines `com.smartwcm.core.userprofile.dao.impl.` is your own defined package and  **line number 40** `UserProfileDaoImpl.getUserProfile`(UserProfileDaoImpl.java:40) is the **culprit**.